# Average current instead of peak current for diode current calculation in SMPS

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

In the switch-mode power supply circuit, I need to know why we use average current instead of peak current to estimate the maximum diode current.

[image]

[image]

In addition, the writer for switch power dissipation uses the RMS value of the current but for this diode uses the average value. What is their operation difference?

[image]

Here you can download the explanations:

https://ufile.io/v1ha838p

Comment: The key is in the title: ***Worst-case Diode Dissipation***.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Could you let me know why we don't use the RMS value instead of the DC value of the current?

Comment: Stop and think about it: how do you calculate the power? You have V and I -- what formula do you use to calculate the power? Maybe the book/course/resource/etc has more hints as you read forward.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I think and read but nothing changed:) ( https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-177.html) regarding this page for a diode with time-varying voltage and current for calculating the power dissipation, we should use the RMS value.

Comment: We can use the DC value instead of RMS value because in this case, RMS value will be almost equal to the average value. For example, if I_out = 0.5A and ΔI = 0.4A. During T_OFF time when the diode conducts current, the RMS value is 0.513A and the average is 0.5A.

Comment: Thank you dear G36, but as I check the textbook it was a general rule for calculating the diode and switch power dissipation and the writer didn't assume or calculate the RMS and average in advance. I put the textbook in the updated post above.

Comment: You can never assume the load will be constant nor the duty cycle or frequency, not that the inductor current will stay in constant conduction mode. But at max current with the smallest R and biggest damping load. the Idc will rise to a rated level  and the AC current will be relatively smaller , if it is still regulated for reasonably low ripple..  But the average diode current could still be 2/3 of the rms diode current and 1/2 the peak diode current for example.

Comment: I appreciate your help and your explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all pretty simple, we are always looking for the average power which is the quantity that is related to our devices temperature rise.

So, we take instantaneous power and average over some time period.
$$ P=\frac{1}{T}\int_{T} v(t)i(t)\mathrm{d}t $$

Now this could be marked as a completed task, then it's up to you finding voltage and current relations and do the dirty job.

Engineering comes now into play, we all love approximations which losing a little of accuracy return a clear picture of the problem

Let's take two classes of devices:

- those that exhibit a rather constant voltage drop (diodes) and model them just as a constant voltage Vd
- those better described with a voltage drop proportional to the current and  model them as a resistance Rd

In the first case

$$ P=\frac{1}{T}\int_{T} V_\mathrm{D}\,i(t)\mathrm{d}t=V_\mathrm{D}\;\underbrace{\frac{1}{T}\int_{T} i(t) \mathrm{d}t}_{I_\mathrm{AVG}}=V_\mathrm{D}I_\mathrm{AVG}$$

average current is needed to calculate the average power.

While in the second one
$$ P=\frac{1}{T}\int_{T} r_\mathrm{D}\,i^2(t)\mathrm{d}t=r_\mathrm{D}\;\underbrace{\frac{1}{T}\int_{T} i^2(t) \mathrm{d}t}_{I_\mathrm{RMS}^2}=r_\mathrm{D}I^2_\mathrm{RMS}$$

we happen to meet the definition of RMS current.

So, in the case posted, diode is modelled as a constant voltage drop and average current is used while MOS is modelled by its rds(on) and RMS current gives the dissipated power.

Comment: I appreciate it. Your point is very comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

The reason peaks are used for pulses is that the RMS can be computed knowing the duty factor.

The RMS value for a pulse is derived from the peak and it's d.f.  Then Vrms * Irms = Pavg.
**There is no rms power, it's just a time interval average of instantaneous product of \$V(t)*I(t)\$.**

Power is measured by Average and this is estimated from the peak with some duty factor.  \$Pavg=V(t)*I(t)*D\$  for t during ON time in 1 cycle.

### other  info

The package and copper layout determines the junction temperature rise from this average power.  Conservative designs will derate this so that the maximum junction temp. does not reach 125'C but rather 85'C for longer life.

Although there is no context or reference to this pasted text, I can't agree entirely with their conclusions as generalizations.

The worst-case current is rarely at steady-state and usually occurs during startup with a load even if there is current limiting per cycle.  The reason is that more energy is stored in the LC components than the worst-case load, so during startup, a soft-start is critical to the reliability and thermal stress.

Thus max. power and temperature rise in all situations must be considered in every part.

Comment: Thank you very much, Tony. Could you let me know why we don't use RMS value instead of DC value of the current?

Comment: DC current is used when it is  constant for some interval then factors like duty cycle extend the period to a cycle. Average current does not work when power is \$P_d=I^2R\$  but when the real-time v(t) I(t) product is computed over some interval, it can be averaged using D..  For the diode they used worst case average in a CCM model. That would not be accurate if it were DCM.

Comment: I appreciate your comment; I've updated the post where the writer uses RMS current for calculating power dissipation of switch.

Comment: Show a link to your text

Comment: I appreciate your help. I placed the link/textbook at the bottom of the main topic.

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with ESR (C) , DCR (L), RdsOn and DSO's but you might learn nothing or a lot from my simulation.  Note the efficiency you can see by the ratio of Pout (max) / Pin (-).   There are much better Bucks than this simulation but here it is interactive and everything is adjustable with a mouse or menu.   https://tinyurl.com/y6jnqwv5